# Programatically suppress window from requesting attention on windows

Tags: java, winapi

I made a program that automates some tasks in another program. The problem is, however, that the window that is being automated tries to gain focus occasionally. This means that even though the task was automated, I still get disturbed by the window popping up here and there.

My question therefore is: How could I prevent this window from gaining focus or flashing on the taskbar?

I'm using winapi for my project and I'm accessing it through java. I can therefore do many things with *hwnd*, as WinApi calls the window reference.

Comment: I wonder if you can make your window a **modal dialog** of the other window. To do this, you'd need to get the hwnd of your own window, I'm sure. What GUI library are you using? How are you using WinAPI? via JNA? JNI?

Comment: I'm in java, so for GUI I use swing I guess. Oh, so I checked now and it uses both `swing` and `awt`. It's not my work frankly.

Comment: For Winapi, I use some Sirius library but basically it just wraps `com.sun.jna`. In winapi, I just call the various window functions, such as `ShowWindow`. I have created myself generic `Window` interface which I implement as `MSWindow`. Answer to this question should lead me to having `preventFocus()` and `preventBlink()` methods.

Comment: What if you call `EnableWindow(hwndParent, FALSE)` on the parent Window?

Comment: It makes nasty sound when I click it. This function is supposed to prevent window from receiving messages - that would kinda break my automation project.

Comment: How are you automating the process anyway? Is UI Automation or MSAA out of the question? If so, do you know what step in your automation process causes it to become foreground?

Comment: In my experience, the best bet is to turn off the foreground locking mechanism altogether (search MSDN for SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT for details).  This is not a friendly thing to do to the user's computer.  However, if this is something you will use only on your *own* computer(s) then that's OK.  It *might* also be acceptable if you know that the user won't be trying to run anything else at the same time your application (other than the application that it automates, of course).